# (pandas) Why does .bfill().ffill() act differently than ffill().bfill() on groups?

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I think I'm missing something basic conceptually, but I'm not able to find the answer in the docs.

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 'b':[5,np.nan, 6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
>>> df
   a    b
0  1  5.0
1  1  NaN
2  2  6.0
3  2  NaN
4  3  NaN
5  3  NaN
```

Using ffill() and then bfill():

```
>>> df.groupby('a')['b'].ffill().bfill()
0    5.0
1    5.0
2    6.0
3    6.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
```

Using bfill() and then ffill():

```
>>> df.groupby('a')['b'].bfill().ffill()
0    5.0
1    5.0
2    6.0
3    6.0
4    6.0
5    6.0
```

Doesn't the second way break the groupings? Will the first way always make sure that the values are filled in only with other values in that group?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()))
0    5.0
1    5.0
2    6.0
3    6.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64

print (df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()))
0    5.0
1    5.0
2    6.0
3    6.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

because in your sample only first `ffill` or `bfill` is [`DataFrameGroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) or [`DataFrameGroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html), second is working with output `Series`. So it break groups, because `Series` has no groups.

```
print (df.groupby('a')['b'].ffill())
0    5.0
1    5.0
2    6.0
3    6.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64

print (df.groupby('a')['b'].bfill())
0    5.0
1    NaN
2    6.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64
```