# Why does pandas Dataframe bfill or ffill yield random results when used with groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following is the example data

```
id,c1,c2
1,1,g1
2,,g2
3,,g1
4,2,g2
5,,g1
6,,g2
7,3,g1
8,,g2
9,,g1
10,4,g2
11,,g1
12,,g2
```

```
df=pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

[image]

I want to groupby `c2`, and forward fill and then backfill `c1` within each group. I expect the following 3 approaches to yield the same results, because "[Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby)". However, `Approach 1` is different from the other two and gives the wrong results: for the row where `id=2`, the filled result is `1`. This is obviously wrong since there is no `c1=1` at all within the `g2` group. Is this a pandas bug? I am using pandas 1.1.3.

### Approach 1

```
df['fill_value']=df.groupby('c2').c1.ffill().bfill()
df
```

[image]

### Approach 2

```
df['fill_value']=df.groupby('c2').c1.ffill()
df['fill_value']=df.groupby('c2').fill_value.bfill()
df
```

[image]

### Approach 3

```
df=df.sort_values('c2')
df['fill_value']=df.groupby('c2').c1.ffill().bfill()
df.sort_values('id')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only found this answer after writing the question. I will close my question, but still publish it so the future generation have a better chance of finding it on Google.

[(pandas) Why does .bfill().ffill() act differently than ffill().bfill() on groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403916/pandas-why-does-bfill-ffill-act-differently-than-ffill-bfill-on-group)