# Pandas: How to fill NaN within a group, only if a certain column contains NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use Pandas to transform a df from this:

|  | Account | Value | OtherColumn | Another Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 1 | A | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | A | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | A | 6.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | A | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | B | 3.0 | 2.0 | NaN |
| 6 | B | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 7 | B | 4.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 8 | B | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 9 | C | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 10 | C | 5.0 | 5.0 | NaN |

To:

|  | Account | Value | OtherColumn | Another Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 1 | A | ***1.0*** | ***1.0*** | ***1.0*** |
| 2 | A | ***1.0*** | ***1.0*** | ***1.0*** |
| 3 | A | 6.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | A | ***6.0*** | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | B | 3.0 | 2.0 | NaN |
| 6 | B | ***3.0*** | ***2.0*** | NaN |
| 7 | B | 4.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 8 | B | ***4.0*** | NaN | NaN |
| 9 | C | ***5.0*** | ***5.0*** | NaN |
| 10 | C | 5.0 | 5.0 | NaN |

What I would like to do is, within a group, is to fill missing data though a combination of ffill() and bfill(). However, I have certain requirements:

If 'Value' is *not* NaN, then I don't want any columns in that row filled.

If 'Value' is NaN it should be filled with the first row above in which 'Value' is not NaN, within the group 'Account'. Then the process should be repeated by filling backward.

What I tried was this:

```
data = {'Account': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'Value': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, 6.0, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, 4.0, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0],
        'OtherColumn': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0],
        'Another Column': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_filled = df.groupby('Account').ffill().bfill()
print(df_filled)
```

However, this returns a dataframe that looks like:

|  | Value | OtherColumn | Another Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 3 | 6.0 | ***1.0*** | ***1.0*** |
| 4 | 6.0 | ***1.0*** | ***1.0*** |
| 5 | 3.0 | 2.0 | NaN |
| 6 | 3.0 | 2.0 | NaN |
| 7 | 4.0 | ***2.0*** | NaN |
| 8 | 4.0 | ***2.0*** | NaN |
| 9 | 5.0 | 5.0 | NaN |
| 10 | 5.0 | 5.0 | NaN |

As you can see, on rows 3 and 4, the OtherColumn and Another Column have been filled with 1.0. I want these rows to remain as NaN. Same with rows 7 and 8 which are filled with the value of 2.0.

I cannot use ffill(1) because the number of rows that need to be forward (or back) filled varies)

Comment: Got it. But please do make your post easier to read by expliciting your desired operation **at the top of your post** instead of scattering it all over it.

Comment: Looks like you need to ffill, bfill on Value column first and then do a groupby on Account, Value to ffill and bfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm doing ffill and bfill on Value column first because it looks like your business logic is to ffill and bfill `OtherColumn` and `Another Column` based on group of `Account` and `Value` or at least I think it should be based on what you have described.

Once we do that, then we can group the dataframe based on `Account` and `Value` and ffill and bfill the group. I'm using here `apply` to do the ffill and bfill since chaining the two methods `.ffill().bfill()` results in a behavior not expected (since result of ffill would be a series and we are applying bfill to a series instead of dataframe). [See this link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403916/pandas-why-does-bfill-ffill-act-differently-than-ffill-bfill-on-group)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Account': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'Value': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, 6.0, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, 4.0, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0],
        'OtherColumn': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0],
        'Another Column': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Account')['Value'].ffill().bfill()
df_filled = df.groupby(['Account', 'Value']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print(df_filled)
```

Output

```
                 Account  Value  OtherColumn  Another Column
Account Value                                               
A       1.0   0        A    1.0          1.0             1.0
              1        A    1.0          1.0             1.0
              2        A    1.0          1.0             1.0
        6.0   3        A    6.0          NaN             NaN
              4        A    6.0          NaN             NaN
B       3.0   5        B    3.0          2.0             NaN
              6        B    3.0          2.0             NaN
        4.0   7        B    4.0          NaN             NaN
              8        B    4.0          NaN             NaN
C       5.0   9        C    5.0          5.0             NaN
              10       C    5.0          5.0             NaN
```

EDIT: You can drop level to get the dataframe without multilevel index

```
df_filled = df_filled.droplevel(['Account', 'Value'])
```

Output

```
   Account  Value  OtherColumn  Another Column
0        A    1.0          1.0             1.0
1        A    1.0          1.0             1.0
2        A    1.0          1.0             1.0
3        A    6.0          NaN             NaN
4        A    6.0          NaN             NaN
5        B    3.0          2.0             NaN
6        B    3.0          2.0             NaN
7        B    4.0          NaN             NaN
8        B    4.0          NaN             NaN
9        C    5.0          5.0             NaN
10       C    5.0          5.0             NaN
```

Comment: Alternative just add `group_keys = False` to the second groupby so the droplevel is not required.